# andengine start game from menu

Tags: java, android, andengine

I want to start a game from a menu. In Eclipse, I have 2 projects, one with the menu, the other the actual game. Both using `SimpleBaseGameActivity` as their base. The examples on the net do something like below. In particular, it creates an intent and starts an activity with that intent. The code below gives a `NoClassDefFoundError` on `MyGame.class`. This is no surprise since `MyGame.class` doesn't exist, but rather `MyGame.apk` does. How do I do this?

```
public boolean onMenuItemClicked(final MenuScene pMenuScene,
        final IMenuItem pMenuItem,
        final float pMenuItemLocalX,
        final float pMenuItemLocalY) {

    switch(pMenuItem.getID()) {
        case MENU_PLAY:
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MyGame.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();       
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

----- edit

I've got it working, with everything in one project, in that when the `menu item` is clicked on, then the game starts. However, when the 'back arrow' is clicked, it doesn't return to the `menu`, but rather to the operating system. The activity definitions in the `manifest` file are below. Does this look correct?

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.mygame.MyGame"
    android:label="@string/mygame_activity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.menu.MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.menu.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

I added this to `MyGame`, but it doesn't get called:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

--- edit
I needed to remove this line:

```
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyGame have to be an activity and it must be mentioned in Android.manifest as an activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Reading this link, it sets the parent activity. So the parent activity would be the menu because the game (the child) would go up to the parent. Is the manifest file that I am editing in the parent or the child project?

Answer (score 4):

first insert in the Manifest in the tags

```
<application>...</application>
```

this tag:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyGame"
        android:label="MygameName" >
    </activity>
```

and change in your code:

```
 public boolean onMenuItemClicked(final MenuScene pMenuScene,
        final IMenuItem pMenuItem,
        final float pMenuItemLocalX,
        final float pMenuItemLocalY) {

switch(pMenuItem.getID()) {

case MENU_PLAY:
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyGame.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();

    }
});
return true;
```

Comment: Finally getting back to this. I've implemented as you've suggested but still get the same error. I'm still in my original quandary, that it is looking for and not surprisingly can't find MyGame.class. According to the link below, classes are compiled into dex format in the apk. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29

Answer (score -1):

Please Remove call to function "finish()" and then it will take you back to the parent activity.